# Fetching data from json inside listbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am having one dropdown and when I select one item from that dropdown a list appears corresponding to that item comes from a json in the list box. But I don't want to have list box, I want to have checkboxes instead so that I can select multiple items. I'm trying to convert this list box into checkboxes but not getting the intended result as i dont want to hardcode data ..i m fetching from json .. Please help!
my html file

```
<form name="myform" id="myForm">

    <select id="dropdown1"></select>
    <div id="listbox" ></div>
    <br>
</form>
```

my js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "data.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(obj) {
            var jsObject = obj;
            var usedNames = [];

            $('<option>', {
                text: 'Select your Option',
                value: '',
                selected: 'selected',
                disabled: 'disabled'
            }).appendTo('#dropdown1');




            $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                if (usedNames.indexOf(value.name) == -1) {
                    $("#dropdown1").append("<option value=" + key + ">" + value.name + "</option>");
                    usedNames.push(value.name);
                }
            $('#dropdown1').change(function() {
                    $('#listbox').empty();

                    $('<option>', {
                        text: 'Select your List Option',
                        value: '',
                        selected: 'selected',
                        disabled: 'disabled'
                    }).appendTo('#listbox');

                    var selection = $('#dropdown1 :selected').text();
                 //   var selection = $('#dropdown1 :selected').text();
                    $.each(jsObject, function(index, value) {
                        if (value['name'] == selection) {
                            var optionHtml = '';
                            for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                                var attr = 'attr' + ('000' + i).substr(-3);
                                optionHtml += '<option value="' + attr + '">' + value[attr] + '</option>';
                            }
                            $('#listbox').append(optionHtml); return false;
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: are you clear what you trying to achieve?

Comment: You have already try to post this question and has been closed!

Comment: But I am not getting how to achecive this as I m taking data from json file